# $\Sigma_1$-soundness

Tags: arithmetic, model-theory, peano-axioms

In a theory of arithmetic like PA, "$\Sigma_1$-sound" means that it proves no false $\Sigma_1$-sentence. What is a false $\Sigma_1$-sentence in PA, does it involve TM ?

Comment: What is "TM"? "Turing machine"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, Turing machine. My intuition is that $\Sigma_1$-false means proved by a TM computation and then denied by the theory.

Comment: A simple example is "there is a proof of a contradiction from PA".

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lévy or arithmetical hierarchy of formulas?

Comment: Yes, I know these hierarchies. How do I get more $\Sigma_1$-false formulas besides "there is a proof of a contradiction from PA" ?

Comment: If you know the hierarchies then a false $\Sigma_1$-sentence is just what it says: a $\Sigma_1$-sentence that is false (usually in the context of arithmetic).  "There is a proof of a contradiction from $\mathsf{PA}$" is one.  Another one is just "$\exists x (x\not= x)$".  Are you sure you know the hierarchies and aren't confusing them for something else?  What do you think a $\Sigma_1$-formula is?

Comment: @JunderscoreH $$\exists x_1\ldots\exists x_k \phi(x_1,\ldots,x_k,\ldots,x_n)$$ where $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_k,\ldots,x_n)$ is quantifier free or bounded quantifier. Is that correct ? But arithmetic is inherently incomplete. So **false** means PA proves its negation. Therefore there are formulas which are neither true nor false. Is that the case ?

Comment: A particular case of a formula which is neither false nor true is I think $\mathbb{Con(PA)}$, is that correct ?

Comment: @JunderscoreH Therefore I have invoked Turing Machines for $\Sigma_1$-soundness so that each formula would be either false or true. $\mathsf{Con(PA)}$ would now be true unlike in mere provability in $\mathsf{PA}$.

Comment: @user122424 False just means not true as in $\psi$ is false iff $\mathsf{N}=\langle \mathbb{N},0,1,+,\cdot\rangle\not\models\psi$.  There's no notion of computability going on with it, and it doesn't depend on whether $\mathsf{PA}$ proves it or not.  The natural numbers exist, and there's a fact of the matter whether $\mathsf{N}=\langle \mathbb{N},0,1,+,\cdot\rangle\models \phi(\vec{x})$ for any given formula $\phi$ and parameters $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{N}$.  $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ is true, but it's independent of $\mathsf{PA}$.

Comment: @JunderscoreH But if you take $\mathbf{N}$ in ZFC, the same problem arises: sometimes $\mathbf{N}\models \psi$ sometimes not and it is not uniquely implied by ZFC theory for a good choice of $\psi$ say for $\psi=\mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$. Is $\mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$ considered true or not ?

Comment: @user122424 Whether $\mathsf{ZFC}$ implies or determines it is also irrelevant.  It doesn't matter whether we know something is true or whether we can figure out whether something is true. Knowledge ≠ truth. You need to distinguish between what follows from just some statements attempting to describe objects and what is actually true about the objects.  Just because different models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ are thinking of different objects when interpretting "$\mathbb{N}$" doesn't mean first-order statements about them have no truth value. It just means those objects have different properties.

Comment: And you still do not make use of Turing Machines to determine that unique truth ? How do you become to know and how do you determine which first order statement is true and which is false ? This is not clear for me yet. If you make use of Turing Machines then you can really see if there is $x$ such that that TM halts and hence $\exists x \phi(x)$ is true.

Comment: @user122424 You build up the notion of truth for first order theories in the same way formulas are built up: for atomic formulas, truth is immediate: equality and relations are given in the model. Then $\mathsf{M}\models \phi\wedge \psi$ iff $\mathsf{M}\models\phi$ and $\mathsf{M}\models\psi$.  $\mathsf{M}\models\neg\phi$ iff $\mathsf{M}\not\models\phi$. $\mathsf{M}\models\exists x \phi$ iff for some $x\in M$, $\mathsf{M}\models\phi(x)$ (whether we can compute such an $x$ is irrelevant).  This gives a notion of truth for all first order formulas and models $\mathsf{M}$.

Comment: And **which** model $\mathsf{M}$ do you take for $\mathbb{N}$ to see whether $\mathsf{M}\models \phi(x)$?

Comment: @user122424 At this point you should just read an introductory logic textbook or ask a separate question about what first-order truth is.  The above works for all models $\mathsf{M}$ (which might have no notion of computation or any relation whatsoever to $\mathbb{N}$) including the standard model of arithmetic $\mathsf{N}=\langle \mathbb{N},0,1,+,\cdot\rangle$.

Comment: So is the first order formula $\mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$ true or false ? There are models of $\mathbb{N}$ which think $\not\models \mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$

Comment: @user122424 There are models of $\mathsf{PA}$ that think $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is false.  Assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, there are models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ whose interpretation of $\mathbb{N}$ (a notion defined by a formula in the language of set theory) thinks that $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is false.  But these models are not standard. $\mathbb{N}$ on its own refers to the natural numbers of the real world.  There it's not clear whether $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is true or not (though most assume so).

Comment: @user122424 Presumably something like the numerals 0, 0', 0'', 0''', etc. See [standard models of arithmetic](http://builds.openlogicproject.org/content/model-theory/models-of-arithmetic/models-of-arithmetic.pdf#page=2).